# Display coverage of inlined-styles in dev-tools

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage, inline-styles

When using Dev-tools' Coverage tab, I can see the ratios of used and unused code for a page, with a useful diff highlighting functions that were used and functions that were not. This works with both JavaScript in separate `.js` files and with JavaScript that has been inlined into my `index.html`.

The site is built with Gatsby, using Styled-components, which means that during the build, its styles are inlined into the `index.html` within a `<style></style>` tag. However DevTools doesn't show any coverage for those styles.

**Is there any way to display coverage for styles that are inlined in html?**